# How to pull data from JSON in Async Task?

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous, android-asynctask

My app pulls data from an API to list view. That works fine. When clicked on a row that is supposed to show more data and it works without error. However there is no actual data showing just empty values.

I believe I'm not doing something in the doInBackground method in the Async task. I believe its something to do with the URL and ID?

Haven't been able to figure this out with self research all day as I'm really new to Java. Thanks.

Code in MainActivity.java:

```
public void showMemberDetailsScreen(int _id) {
    mMembersListScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mMemberDetailsScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (NetworkUtils.isConnected(this)) {
        GetDetailsTask task = new GetDetailsTask(this);
        task.execute(_id);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: NOT CONNECTED");
    }
}

/**
 * Populate the member details screen with data.
 * 
 * @param _name
 * @param _birthday
 * @param _gender
 * @param _twitterId
 * @param _numCommittees
 * @param _numRoles
 */
public void populateMemberDetailsScreen(String _name, String _birthday, String _gender, 
        String _twitterId, String _numCommittees, String _numRoles) {

    TextView tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    Log.i(TAG, "populateMemberDetailsScreen: NAME = " + _name);
    tv.setText(_name);

    tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_birthday);
    tv.setText(_birthday);

    tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_gender);
    tv.setText(_gender);

    tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_twitter_id);
    tv.setText(_twitterId);

    tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_num_committees);
    tv.setText(_numCommittees);

    tv = (TextView)mMemberDetailsScreen.findViewById(R.id.text_num_roles);
    tv.setText(_numRoles);
}

OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _parent, View _view, int _position, long _id) {
        // TODO: Show the members detail screen
        Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: RAN");

        showMemberDetailsScreen((int)_id);
        Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: POSITION = " + _position);

    }
};
```

Code in GetDetailsTask.java:

```
public class GetDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, HashMap<String, String>> {
private static final String TAG = "GetDetailsTask";
private static final String API_URL = "https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/person/ ";

private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
private static final String GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TWITTER_ID = "twitter_id";
private static final String NUM_COMMITTEES = "num_committees";
private static final String NUM_ROLES = "num_roles";

private MainActivity mActivity;

public GetDetailsTask(MainActivity _activity) {
    mActivity = _activity;
}

@Override
protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Integer... _params) {

    // Add member ID to the end of the URL
    String data = NetworkUtils.getNetworkData(API_URL + _params[0]);

    HashMap<String, String> retValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(data);

        String name = response.optString("name");
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: NAME = " + name);
        retValues.put(NAME, name);

        String birthday = response.optString("birthday");
        retValues.put(BIRTHDAY, birthday);

        String gender = response.optString("gender_label");
        retValues.put(GENDER, gender);

        String twitterId = response.optString("twitterid");
        retValues.put(TWITTER_ID, twitterId);

        if (response.has("committeeassignments")) {
            JSONArray committeeArray = response.optJSONArray("committeeassignments");
            int numCommittees = committeeArray.length();
            retValues.put(NUM_COMMITTEES, "" + numCommittees);
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: NUM COMMITTESS = " + numCommittees);
        } else {
            retValues.put(NUM_COMMITTEES, "" + 0);
        }

        if (response.has("roles")){
            JSONArray rolesArray = response.optJSONArray("roles");
            int numRoles = rolesArray.length();
            retValues.put(NUM_ROLES, "" + numRoles);
        } else {
            retValues.put(NUM_ROLES, "" + 0);
        }

    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retValues;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> _result) {
    super.onPostExecute(_result);
    if (_result != null) {
        String name = _result.get(NAME);
        String birthday = _result.get(BIRTHDAY);
        String gender = _result.get(GENDER);
        String twitterId = _result.get(TWITTER_ID);
        String numCommittees = _result.get(NUM_COMMITTEES);
        String numRoles = _result.get(NUM_ROLES);

        mActivity.populateMemberDetailsScreen(name, birthday, gender, twitterId, numCommittees, numRoles);
    }
}
```

}

Code in Member.java:

```
public class Member {

private int mId;
private String mName;
private String mParty;

public Member() {
    mId = 0;
    mName = mParty = "";
}

public Member(int _id) {
    this();
    mId = _id;
}

public Member(int _id, String _name) {
    this(_id);
    mName = _name;
}

public Member(int _id, String _name, String _party) {
    this(_id, _name);
    mParty = _party;
}

public void setId(int _id) {
    mId = _id;
}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setName(String _name) {
    mName = _name;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setParty(String _party) {
    mParty = _party;
}

public String getParty() {
    return mParty;
}
```

}

Comment: please explain more. it's really hard to understand your problem :(

Comment: Sorry about that. My URL is pulling data as you can test the link and once I click on a person in the list view I want my screen to display more details about that person. However it is not showing anything just empty results. You can see in my log " String name = response.optString("name");
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: NAME = " + name);" that it returns a empty string.

Comment: in doInBackground, check `String data` have correct data or not?

Comment: It is correct data.

Comment: try change `optString` to `getString`. After that, im sure you will receive some exception, then you should read the exception message and fix

Comment: have you fix it after changing

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface MainView.java

```
public interface MainView {
void populateMemberDetailsScreen(String _name, String _birthday, String _gender, 
        String _twitterId, String _numCommittees, String _numRoles);
void showMemberDetailsScreen(int _id);
}
```

Then implement it in MainActivity.
On your GetDetailsTask.java:

```
MainView _view;
public GetDetailsTask(MainView _view) {
    this._view = _view;
}
```

onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> _result) {
    super.onPostExecute(_result);
    if (_result != null) {
        String name = _result.get(NAME);
        String birthday = _result.get(BIRTHDAY);
        String gender = _result.get(GENDER);
        String twitterId = _result.get(TWITTER_ID);
        String numCommittees = _result.get(NUM_COMMITTEES);
        String numRoles = _result.get(NUM_ROLES);
        if (_view != null)
           _view.populateMemberDetailsScreen(name, birthday, gender, twitterId, numCommittees, numRoles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Going to implement your answer and I don't get your second step. I have a created a interface and fixed the code in onPostExecute. Where to implement the second step?

Comment: public class MainActivity implements MainView {//your code here}

Comment: Gotcha, did that and it's still spitting out the same thing it was which is an empty string.. my logs are NAME =             . All steps were completed correctly.